# How to write an eclipse plug-in to format C++14 source code?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, clang

In eclipse CDT, one can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to format C++14 source code in current editor.

However, the default CDT formatter has a few annoying bugs. So I want to write a formatter of my own. I know it is not an easy work to write a non-trivial one, but I have a powerful tool: **clang-format**.

By using **clang-format**, it will be so easy like homework to write a C++14 source code formatter. However, the real obstacle is writing the eclipse plug-in. I just want to overload the default handler of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

How to achieve the goal?

Comment: why dont you modify CDT's formatter to do what you want?  Surely that has to be easier than fusing Eclipse with CDT together with Clang.

Comment: @IraBaxter, how to modify? What I want is just how to modify the existing formatter.

Comment: Eclipse plugins are always written in Java - do you know any Java?

Comment: @greg-449, I think java is not a problem. The real problem is understanding eclipse's plugin-based architecture.

Comment: CDT is open source.   Look at it, figure out the part you don't like, and change it.  If your problem is to modify CDT, yes, you will have to understand the plug-in architecture, but presumably only to find your way around inside  CDT.   You'll have to understand CDT, too, obfiously.  But your alternative, Clang, means you have to understand Clang, then understand eclipse plugins, *build one*, and some interface it to Clang.   The CDT path seems easier to me.  YMMV.

Comment: Is this what you mean to do: https://github.com/schulmar/clang_format_eclipsecdt

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to share the Eclipse plugin named **CppStyle**. http://wangzw.github.io/CppStyle/

CppStyle integrates clang-format as another code formatter for Eclipse CDT and support to format the C/C++ code using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F`. In additional you can enable CDT to format the source file on save.

CppStyle also integrates [cpplint.py](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#cpplint) to check the coding styles. Check and mark style issues on the CDT editor when the user is about to save the source file.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Especially glad it automatically located the .clang-format file correctly!